# Failed to assign to property 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.MenuItem.Click'

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am trying to inherit a usercontrol for the first time but have been facing a lot of errors.

Here is the **Base UserControl - Generic_Icon**

**XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="project.Icons.Generic_Icon"
    xmlns:ob="clr-namespace:project.Objects"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="120" d:DesignWidth="120">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5,10,6"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBasePressedForegroundBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0">
                                <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Button x:Name="button" Click="Icon_button_Click" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" Padding="0">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!--<Grid.Background>
                <RadialGradientBrush>
                    <GradientStop Color="#ff31c8f5" Offset="0.514"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#0016DAC0" Offset="1"/>
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </Grid.Background>-->
            <Image x:Name="Img" Margin="6" Source="/Assets/Icon Pack/Camera.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Title" Grid.Row="1" Text="Camera" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </Button>
    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        <toolkit:ContextMenu>
            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Remove" Click="Remove_Icon_Click"/>
            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Replace" Click="Replace_Icon_Click"/>
        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
</UserControl>
```

**cs**

```
public partial class Generic_Icon : UserControl
    {
        public event EventHandler remove;
        public event EventHandler replace;
        public EventArgs e = null;
        public delegate void EventHandeler(object c, EventArgs e);
        public Generic_Icon()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public ImageSource get_image_source()
        {
            return Img.Source;
        }
        public String get_title()
        {
            return Title.Text;
        }
        public virtual void Icon_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("clicked");
        }
        public void Remove_Icon_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            remove(this, e);
        }
        public void Replace_Icon_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            replace(this, e);
        }

    }
```

**Derived UserControl Camera
XAML**

```
<icon:Generic_Icon x:Class="project.Icons.Camera"
    xmlns:ob="clr-namespace:project.Objects"
    xmlns:icon="clr-namespace:project.Icons"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="120" d:DesignWidth="120">

</icon:Generic_Icon>
```

**cs**

```
public partial class Camera : Generic_Icon
    {

        public Camera()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Title.Text = "Camera";
            //Uri imageUri = new Uri("/Assets/Icon Pack/Camera.png", UriKind.Relative);
            //BitmapImage imageBitmap = new BitmapImage(imageUri);
            //Img.Source = imageBitmap;
        }
        public override void Icon_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("clicked");
        }
    }
```

when i try to put this Camera UserControl in my MainPage.xaml, i get this error - "Failed to assign to property 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.MenuItem.Click'. [Line: 83 Position: 53]

this line and position brings me to Generic_Icon.xaml at this line - `<toolkit:MenuItem Header="Remove" Click="Remove_Icon_Click"/>`

i tried to change the parameters of this function Remove_Icon_Click from

```
public void Remove_Icon_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
```

to

```
public void Remove_Icon_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

but both are giving same error.
The code does compile but gives XamlParseError on start of the app at InitializeComponent() of Generic_Icons with inner exception same as before.

Comment: Side note, how does an icon becomes a UserControl ? Aren't you complexifying the whole thing ?

Comment: @Aybe May be you are right. but i dont have enough experience with inheriting xaml + code behind. can you point me in right direction? I am unable to find any useful example on this.

Comment: Explain what you are trying to achieve there might be a simpler approach than the one you are currently doing.

Comment: @Aybe I want to make a template UserControl called Generic_Icons. Whose XAML is same as above as all icons derived from it will have the same Xaml. there are two events (remove, replace) that are also going to be inherited. they are fired when ContextMenu items are clicked. One function Icon_button_Click is also inherited but will be overriden in all base classes. Icons image and title of icon is changed in Base class constructor

Comment: What I mean, what is the final use of this ? Currently you have an Image inside a Button and a ContextMenu but why for ? What kind of interaction you are looking for ?

Comment: See my answer and update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

So what are you looking for ?

- the bar of buttons at bottom like in Android ?
- context menu icons ?

About inheritance,

As I said one would do that with `Control` only and regarding your need (setting an image for a derived type) it is **really** inappropriate. Also setting image source in the constructor is just a bad practice; you should stick by having 1 control and create many instances of it like below :

```
<StackPanel>
    <phoneApp1:MyIconControl ImageSource="Icon1.png" />
    <phoneApp1:MyIconControl ImageSource="Icon2.png" />
</StackPanel>
```

Alternatively you could define styles for each type of button (way better IMO)

So give the exact details of what you are expecting in your UI and the behavior you expect, I'll craft some code then.

---

First, you cannot derive from `UserControl` as you do, with `Control` you can but with it you are on your own (no XAML part).

I've added an `ImageSource` dependency property to the control which will update the image in it.

XAML :

```
<UserControl x:Class="PhoneApp1.MyIconControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
             FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
             FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
             Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
             d:DesignHeight="480"
             d:DesignWidth="480"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Name="UserControl1">
    <Grid Background="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}">
        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
            <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                <toolkit:MenuItem Click="RemoveImageClick" Header="Remove image" />
                <toolkit:MenuItem Click="ReplaceImageClick" Header="Replace image" />
            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image x:Name="Image1"
               Margin="6"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight"
                   FontSize="16"
                   Text="Camera" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code :

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace PhoneApp1
{
    public partial class MyIconControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ImageSource", typeof (ImageSource), typeof (MyIconControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(ImageSource), OnImageSourceChanged));

        public MyIconControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ImageSource ImageSource
        {
            get { return (ImageSource) GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void OnImageSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var control = (MyIconControl) d;
            var imageSource = e.NewValue as ImageSource;
            control.Image1.Source = imageSource;
        }

        private void RemoveImageClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ImageSource = null;
        }

        private void ReplaceImageClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            /* Here for instance you could open the pictures folder
             * let the user choose one and set the ImageSource with it
             * like ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(yourimage.png)); */
        }
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
<phoneApp1:MyIconControl ImageSource="Assets/ApplicationIcon.png" />
```

**Explain what you want to achieve in clear terms, a context menu for removing an image doesn't make any sense to me. What kind of app. you are trying to do ? And I'll update my answer from there.**

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what am trying to achieve. I have implemented it but without inheritance. So i still need inheritance. http://imgur.com/k34PBKr (I didnt wanted to share it but as you are really trying to help so..). There are many Icons. All have same Xaml just different images and name. They fire the same events too , when context menu item is selected. And they all have a function that will be called when these icons are tapped to navigate to there corresponding Xaml.